# What is the relationship between the standard topology and the floor topology on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology

[image]

My question: What is the relationship between the standard topology and the 
floor topology on $\mathbb{R}$?

This is what I did for proving this, I showed that standard topology is a subset of floor topology. 
I have a concern, will it be the other way around?? If not, why?? I am guessing that it wont be but I don't know how to explain it.

Can someone help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any basis element in the standard topology is open in the floor topology, so the floor topology is at least as fine as the standard topology.  To show that the containment is strict, you just need to show that there is a set that is open in the floor topology but not open in the standard topology.  But if, say, $[0, 1)$ were open in the standard topology, what would that say about a standard-topology neighborhood of the point $0$?

Comment: If $[0,1)$ is open in the standard topology, then 0 is not the neighborhood of it, $1/4$, $1/2$ will be neighborhood of that half open interval. Does this mean that floor topology is not a subset of standard topology ?

Comment: I bet you already know that is $[0,1)$ isn't open or closed in the stand topology and you're overthinking this.

Comment: Its half open interval, so $[0,1)$ means $0 <= x <1$, therefore 0 should be there in the standard topology, but I know that $(0,1]$ is not the neighborhood of the point 1, similarly $[0,1)$ is not the neighborhood of $0$. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that each basic open subset $(a,b)$ of the standard topology is open in the "floor topology" (also known as "lower limit topology" (Munkres), or Sorgenfrey topology (most topologists), as you showed via one way: $x \in (a,b)$ then $x \in [x,b) \subseteq (a,b)$ etc.

So the floor topology is finer (larger) and strictly so: each basic set $[a,b)$ is by definition open in the floor topology, but the left hand point $a$ is not an interior point of it in the standard topology (suppose $\exists c< d: a \in (c,d) \subseteq [a,b)$ then any point $c'$ with $c < c' < a$ is in $(c,d)$ but not in $[a,b)$ contradiction), so $[a,b)$ is not standard open. The inclusion is strict.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wanted this. Appreciate it!!